# Stageros crashes frequently on launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a recurring problem with stageros crashing immediately on launching any of the launch files in navigation_stage.

I use diamondback, and the nav stack downloaded from the ROS repositories. Occasionally on launching the files in navigation_stage, stageros crashes with the following log:

http://pastebin.com/VFHuxJMp

Once this happens, roslaunch doesn't quit by itself, I have to do a kill -9. Also, subsequent launches of these files leads to stageros crash.

I generally resolve this problem by *rebooting* by system. This works nearly always.

Any better ideas or suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10452/stageros-crashes-frequently-on-launch/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-06-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-30**:
Can you try launching stageros in gdb (directions: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) and output the backtrace when it crashes? Use the `bt` command after the crash, get all of the output and then update your question with it (or a link to it).

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2011-06-30**:
Nothing except that "stageros has died with log file ~/.ros/logs/<somelog.log>"

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-30**:
That log doesn't seem to contain anything unusual. Is there any error output in the terminal you start the launchfile from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No activity for > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0